# Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC Run the query only once when running the program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to write a query When the program first runs, query Add values ​​to the database?

I want this query to run only once

What is the best solution?

Comment: Is your question really: "How to run code once at startup of the application"?

Comment: query executable in startup?

Comment: What do you use to connect to the DB? EF Core?

Comment: @Markus Deibel  I want to do a query to add some to my table for example :

`_contex.Role.add(); _contex.savechange()` somthing like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to run dbcontext when the application started, I suggest you could try to asp.net core lifetime method to run codes in the Configure method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

In the startup.cs Configure method add below codes:

```
        lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(
         () => AddLogs(app));
```

Addlogs method:

```
    static void AddLogs(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {

        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
        {
            //Check the table or role is exsited or not to make sure below codes will just start once.
            if (true)
            {

                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TestDbcontext>();

                var list = context.Admissions.ToList();
                //dbcontext.Admissions.Add(new Admission() { });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

---

Update:

lifetime is a parameter which we could passed to the startup.cs Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
```

Comment: `lifetime` For what package?

Comment: @AliKhansari , any update? Does my reply solve your issue?